# Convert date to epoch time ignoring system timezone

Tags: c, timezone, timestamp

I have written the following code to convert date to timestamp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm date_time;
    char date_time_buf[255];
    char date_time_hdr[255]={0};
    strncpy(date_time_hdr,"Thu, 02 Mar 2017 05:54:28 GMT",255);
    memset(&date_time, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime(date_time_hdr, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &date_time);
    memset(date_time_buf, 0, 255);
    strftime(date_time_buf, 255, "%s", &date_time);
    int p=atoi(date_time_buf);
    printf("time is %d \r\n", p); 
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to convert date to timestamp. But facing an issue.
The timestamp is offset by 5 hrs 30 minutes which is the timezone of my linux machine. But I don't want that. Is there a way to ignore system timezone?

Comment: Since you are using POSIX.1 [`strptime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), you really should add the `posix` tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `strftime()` to format the broken down time `struct tm` as an integer, and parsing it using `atoi()`, you can use the simple but nonstandard [`timegm()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) function.

Even though `timegm()` is not in POSIX, it is provided by most POSIXy systems. If you want your code to be portable across POSIXy systems, you can use a workaround (as described in some versions of the `timegm` man page):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

time_t alt_timegm(struct tm *from)
{
    char   *tz;
    time_t  result;
    int     saved_errno;

    tz = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz)
        tz = strdup(tz);

    setenv("TZ", "", 1); /* TZ empty refers to UTC */
    tzset();

    errno = 0;
    result = mktime(from);
    saved_errno = errno;

    setenv("TZ", tz, 1);
    free(tz);

    errno = saved_errno;
    return result;
}
```

This workaround does have the drawback that it temporarily modifies the current timezone, which affects other threads executing any timezone-related functions. In a single-threaded process this is not an issue (as the timezone-related functions are not async-signal safe, so they aren't to be used in signal handlers).

In multithreaded programs, one should serialize all accesses to the timezone related functions -- `alt_timegm()` above, `mktime()`, `localtime()`, and so on --, to ensure each function is run with the proper timezone set.

The `timegm()` implementations in Linux and BSDs are thread-safe; that is, they do not modify the timezone.

Using the above, parsing a string using an `strptime()` format to an Unix timestamp is easy:

```
const char *parse_utc(const char *s, const char *format, time_t *to)
{
    char      *result;
    struct tm  t_parts;
    time_t     t;

    if (!s || !format) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    result = strptime(s, format, &t_parts);
    if (!result) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    errno = 0;
    t = alt_timegm(&t_parts);
    if (to)
        *to = result;

    return (const char *)result;
}
```

The above `parse_utc()` parses a string `s` using strptime() format `format`, saving the UTC timestamp to `to` if not NULL, returning the pointer to the first unparsed character in string `s`.

Setting `errno = 0` in the above functions may look strange, but it is because the `mktime()` (and `timegm()`) function *may or may not* set `errno` in case of an error; it just returns `(time_t)-1`. This means that it is impossible to reliably determine whether a `(time_t)-1` (corresponding to last second of year 1969 in UTC`) is an actual valid timestamp, or an error return.

In other words, if `errno != 0` after a call to `parse_utc()`, there was an error. (Note that if the string or format was invalid, `parse_utc()` returns `NULL`, with `errno == EINVAL`.) If `errno == 0` but `*to == (time_t)-1`, it depends on the architecture whether the time string actually referred to the last second of year 1969 in UTC, or if it was an error; we simply do not know.